# Can BAM and CEP monitor requests from client like Zipkin

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

I am wondering if I can use BAM and CEP to monitor requests from client, and even find the bottleneck of the service.
I found zipkin, a project that could do this, but the base of my application is WSO2, I don't want to get other projects from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use BAM/CEP for this. If you need real time monitoring you can use CEP and you can use BAM for batch process. From BAM 2.4.0 onwards, CEP features have been added inside BAM also hence you can use BAM and do real time analytics.

What type of services are involved with your scenario? Depends on this you can use already existing data publisher or write new data publisher for BAM/CEP to publish your request details. For example if you are having chain of axis2 webservice calls for a request from client, and you want to monitor where the bottle neck/more time consumed, then you may use the service stats publishing, and monitor the average time take to process the message which will help you to see where the actual delay has been introduced. For this you can use existing service statistics publisher feature. Also BAM will allow you to create your own dashboard to visualize, hence you can customize the dashboard.

Also with BAM 2.4.0 we have introduced notifications feature also which you can define some threshold value and configure to send notification if that cross that threshold value.

Comment: great! and you remind me of the service statistic sample. I will go through that and back to you later. Thanks!